# How to see dart binary file or where can I see the source code?

Tags: flutter, dart

[This image is the result ls -la at flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWlH6.png)

I have been reading some dart files how `flutter` command is executed.
I stacked because `flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart` file is a binary file. Now I can't read it. How can I read this file?

I found out `dart-sdk` repository in Github.
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/stable/sdk/bin

I thought this `dart` file is the source code. But actually, the file size is smaller than the binary file.
Although I replace my local `dart` file, it doesn't work.

Now I know `flutter analyze` command calls as follows

1. Run `flutter analyze` command
2. `flutter/bin/flutter` is called
3. `flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh` is called
4. `shared::execute` function is called in `shared.sh`
5. `flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart` is called.

But I can't see the `dart` file. Because the file is a binary file.

[This is the `dart` binary file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEEI8.png)

Comment: `bin/` directories contain binaries (although sometimes "binaries" are executable scripts).  If you want to see the source, look in the `lib/` directories.  It's unclear from your question exactly what source code you're looking for.  Are you asking about the `dart` command?  The `flutter` command?  Something else?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where's the `lib/` directory? I just attached the image. Please check it. I would like to know which files are called after I run `flutter analyze` command.

Comment: I mean you want to look in `lib/` *instead* of `bin/`. `lib/` is a sibling directory. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/stable/sdk/lib.  You still haven't explained exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for the `dart` source code for the directory `flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin`. Where's the source code in the https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/stable/sdk/lib ?

Comment: So you want the source code to the `dart` command-line tool itself? I believe that's https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/stable/pkg/dartdev.

Comment: Yes. I feel the source code is in http://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/stable/pkg/dartdev. But which file?

Comment: Uh, all of it?  Why would you think it's built from a single source file?  Again; *exactly* what are you looking for?  What do you *ultimately* want to accomplish?  People would be able to help you better if you weren't vague and explained exactly what problem you're trying to solve.  Also see the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: My question is very simple. I would like to see the source file. Where can I find the source file for that binary file(dart)? I just attached the binary file. Now I can't see the contents. Because I can't understand what the binary file is doing.

Comment: As I already explained, there isn't a single source file.  Like most non-trivial programs, the source code is organized across multiple files.  I could help you find the relevant file(s) for you if you explained what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will find dart niomary file in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/stable/sdk/bin/cache/dart-sdk on this path if ypu download flutter sdk from flutter site